# Экспорт данных из Excel файла в БД

Tags: delphi, excel, firebird

Нужно перегнать данные из Excel файлов (их у меня 10 и в каждом файле больше 9000 записей) в БД (Использую СУБД Firebird).

Как максимально быстро произвести экспорт данных, не растягивая это удовольствие на часы?

Answer (score 2):

Способ А (менее скучный):

1. Читаете XLS.
2. Построчно оборачиваете в `INSERT ...`  и кладете в СУБД.

Способ Б (скучный):

1. Берем конвертор, которых в интернетах навалом и не мучаемся.
2. Пункт списка

Способ В (мм... экзотический) подходит, если схема таблицы в БД и в Excel совпадает:

1. Кидаем на форму TDBGridEh (если есть пакет EhLib), TDataSource, настраиваем источник данных.
2. У грида включаем RowSelect и все EditActions.
3. Запускаем приложение.
4. Копипастаем кусок данных из экселя в грид. )

Answer (score 0):

В InterBase Expert есть функция импорта данных из файлов Excel

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Answer (score 0):

1 переводите XLS в CSV

2 Грузите CSV в TstringLiSt

3 В цикле парсите строку от TstringList и пишите в FireBird

При правильном построении  кода не займет много времени